Fail with error 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance' - Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0b9ee5ffb6ed1b54460e1131094c29e6f914bfd9e35e021f48ca3b9618fdc405
I had an issue during staking $meme in Stakeland.
The amount deducted from my Metamask wallet but not added to my meme staked amount on stakeland.
The transaction on the eitherscan shows an error occurred during contract execution.
My wallet address is 0x175d15736cEdeeD9B96932cE98A5e4FD53A02867
Transaction hash on eitherscan is 0x0b9ee5ffb6ed1b54460e1131094c29e6f914bfd9e35e021f48ca3b9618fdc405

The transaction reverting implies that your tx has not altered the Ethereum state, meaning that you lost no tokens. You probably didn't have any in the first place considering the tx revert message.

kindly inform me what should i do to restore my tokens. I'm not a developer and I don't have any idea about how it works.

What do you mean restore tokens? Nothing is taken when a transaction reverts.
